# Loop through all possible options in a filtered column

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for help with a macro that will use a column's filter to go through each possible selection on the filter. It will then copy and paste the filtered selection, clear the filter, and reapply to the next possible option on the filter range. Any ideas on this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to offer your own attempt first. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

This is only an example............you must adapt it to your data and schema.  Say we have a *data* tab like:

[image]

We want to run all the options on **Type** *(that is alpha,beta,gamma)* and capture them separately.  This macro:

```
Sub macroxx()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = Sheets("data")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("results")
    Dim ary(1 To 3) As String, tablee As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    j = 1
    ary(1) = "alpha"
    ary(2) = "beta"
    ary(3) = "gamma"
    Set tablee = sh1.Range("A1:C28")

    For i = 1 To 3
        tablee.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ary(i)
        tablee.Copy sh2.Cells(1, j)
        j = j + 4
    Next i
End Sub
```

We run the options and place the results in the *results* tab:

[image]